# How to convert string to json in perl

Tags: json, perl

I am very new to perl so please help me out in following

I have one perl script to execute telnet command. This script receives response from server as string. Actually server create a json string and then it sends to client program but client program is showing it as `string`

Question : How I can convert this string to json and read data from this json string.

I have json string with structure similar to following

```
[{"success":"21","data":[{"name":"tester","lastname":"project"}]}]
```

---

Following are the last lines where I have tried to convert it to json

```
@lines = $telnet->waitfor('/$/');
my @json;
@json = @{decode_json(@lines)};
```

It prints output as below

```
HASH(0x1af068c)
```

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a snippet to convert the JSON.  Modified to catch errors.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON::XS;
use Try::Tiny;
use Data::Dumper::Concise;

my $data = qq<[{"success":"21","data":[{"name":"tester","lastname":"project"}]}]>;

my $decoded;

try {
    $decoded = JSON::XS::decode_json($data);
}
catch {
    warn "Caught JSON::XS decode error: $_";
};

print Dumper $decoded;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
Could you please help me in getting value of "success"?

I tried it as below, but not working. I am sure that I am doing something wrong :( .  I don't know much (actually anything) about perl 
    print $decoded->{'success'};
    print $decoded['success'];

Thanks again!

Comment: The decode function dies on error.  I modified the example to use the module Try::Tiny to catch the error.

Comment: Thanks once again :)

How I can access values of "success" i.e. 21 from $decoded?

Comment: $decoded->[0]{success} - [0] is the array index, {success} is the hash key.

Comment: I was trying to access as $decoded[0]->{"success"} .. silly mistake.

Great Thanks!!! :)

Answer (score 5):

I think there is a simpler one:

```
use JSON ();

$content = "{WHATEVER JSON CONTENT}";

$content = JSON->new->utf8->decode($content);
```