# How to read a dictionary inside a quoted JSON string from a API call and get a length of that list using Perl

Tags: perl, list, dictionary, key

I have this quoted JSON string from a API call using URL.

```
my $person = '[{"id":"1232334", "name": "james"}]'
```

How to get a `length` of that list and `read a dictionary` key-value based inside that list using Perl:

desired output:

```
length = 1
person id : 1232334
person name : james
```

Thanks!

Comment: That first statement is not valid Perl code. It looks like an unquoted JSON string?

Comment: +1 I'm very newbie to perl, so excuse me for using the wrong terminology. fixed. thank you @TLP

Comment: Its still not valid Perl code. It would have to be `"[{'id':'23123'... }]"` -- quoted.

Comment: it's not clear what you mean by "I have this..."; where is your input coming from?  Or is there some perl data structure (not a JSON string) already existing?

Comment: in your other question, you show proper json with `"`, not `'`, quotes; have you just mistyped it here?

Comment: @ysth you are correct. fixed. thank you again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please don't start all your questions from the original JSON string.  You have JSON; first turn it into a perl datastructure, then ask how to do X, Y, or Z with that datastructure (showing us what it looks like with `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper $datastructure;`)

Assuming you've already decoded the JSON, you will have this:

```
    [
      {
        'name' => 'james',
        'id' => '1232334'
      }
    ]
```

Assuming it is stored in `$people`:

```
print 'length = ', scalar(@$people), "\n";
print "person id : $people->[0]{'id'}\n";
print "person name : $people->[0]{'name'}\n";
```

Comment: Thank you! this seems very logic! I'm getting an error message : `Can't use string ("[{"id":"1232334", "name": "james"}]"` because when I used  `print Dumper` I realized that the json is astring looks like this `'[{"id":"1232334", "name": "james"}]'` with quote, not just `[{"id":"1232334", "name": "james"}]`.

Comment: you must decode the json first; see my answer to your previous question.

Comment: +1 for the info! Thank you for pointing me to the right direction!!! using your suggestion I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655487/how-to-convert-string-to-json-in-perl and problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution:

```
my $person = [{id => '1232334', name => 'james'}];

my $size = @$person;  # sizeof array_ref 
print "length = $size\n";
for my $i (@$person) {
    foreach $key (keys %{$i}) {
        print "person $key => $i->{$key}\n";
    }
}
```

output:

```
length = 1
person name => james
person id => 1232334
```